# Help with cron syntax

Tags: cpanel, cron

I need to setup a cronjob on my webhost.

The documentation for my webapp reads as follows:

> you will need to create following
>   cronjob: /public_html/cake/console/cake
>   -app /public_html/app master

Also, I want any output written to a log file.  My hosts documentation says this:

> You can have cron send an email
>   everytime it runs a command. If you do
>   not want an email to be sent for an
>   individual cron job you can redirect
>   the command's output to /dev/null like
>   this: mycommand >/dev/null 2>&1

I don't know the syntax to implement this from a cron job.

Comment: How often do you want the cron job to execute?

Comment: then do not use it ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: every 6 hrs.... but my host has fields to setup the time, the hosting page looks like this:http://img574.imageshack.us/img574/9774/cron.jpg

Comment: Which host are you using?

Comment: What will stop people from executing your cron job if they know the direct URL to it? You should implement some basic authentication for it like a secret key that your application checks before executing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot that you posted, you just need to know the correct path of the command that you are trying to run.  It's possible that you just need to remove the leading '/' from your command and the path that you specify after `-app`.  This assumes that your host sets up the cronjob to run as your user and that your public_html directory has its root in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this guide for [Crontab Syntax](http://linuxmoz.com/crontab-syntax-tutorial/) and this tutorial to [disable crontab mail](http://linuxmoz.com/disable-crontab-mail/) (there are a couple of options in the tutorial to disable cron from emailing you the script output).